# Where are Kohana config files?

Tags: configuration, installation, kohana

I've just installed Kohana 3.0.4.2 and I have run the index.php file successfully.  According to the documentation, the next step is to edit the config files in the application/config folder.  I have that folder but there are no files in it!  I downloaded the package again to make sure it wasn't corrupted, but the same problem exists.  Why is the application/config folder empty?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking at outdated (2.*) documentation. The only config file to edit after an install is `application/bootstrap.php`. There is some configuration in `index.php`, but you really shouldn't be touching that unless you want to change the directories things are stored in.

The config folder is used for config files of your custom classes. Since you obviously don't have any in an empty project, the folder is empty. You can see an example of them in use by looking at `system/config`, where the config files for some of the system classes lie.

As of now, the best docs are the [unofficial Kohana wiki](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php). There's also the [official docs](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.kohana), but they're a work in progress.

Answer (score 4):

One of the best things about Kohana 3 is that it's extensible and really modular.

In you case, there are no config files by default, you only have the clean framework with couple of modules ( you'll find them in the /modules folder ). Every modul has pretty much the same hierarchy as application folder, so you'll probably find the default config files there.

If you need database config, go to /modules/database/config/ and you'll find the default one, copy it to application/config and you've overwriten the default one from being used ( Kohana autoload just works this way; first looks for files in application folder, then the loaded modules folder(s), and the system (framework) folder is the last.

Comment: We decided to go with Code Igniter.  Kohana seems to be better software, but the documentation is too sparse and confusing.  It's too hard to determine if I'm looking at the documentation for the correct version.  The developer community for CI is much better, too.